# Creating view-model for each UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, design-patterns, mvvm

I'm stuck on a design decision with creating view-models for table view's cells. Data for each cell is provided by a data source class (has an array  of `Contacts`). In `MVVM` only view-model can talk to model, but it doesn't make sense to put data source in view-model because it would make possible to access data for all cells, also it's wrong to put data source in view controller as it must not have reference to the data. There are some other key moments:

- Each cell must have it's own instance of view-model not a shared one
- `cellForRowAtindexPath` must not be placed in a view-model because
  it shouldn't contain any UI references
- View/ViewController's view-model should not interact with cell's view-model

What's the right way to "insert" data source for cells in `MVVM`'s relationship ? Thanks.

Comment: Unless you are using an additional framework such as React, MVVM doesn't really work in iOS as iOS controls don't have data binding.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm using delegate pattern instead of React, it's more code but it's more clear and debugging is not a pain

Comment: The model has to be owned by something... so, yeah, for iOS that can be tricky. But when feeding a view-model object, feed it the most post-computed/post-fetched values possible from them model, and try to NOT reference the model in the view-model after the view-model obj is initialized. You should inject the needed values/refs from the model into the view-model (i.e. dependency injection) at its initialization. @Jorge Ortiz has a good answer.

Answer (score 117):

Let me start with some theory. MVVM is a specialization of the [Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) (or Application Model) for Microsoft's Silverlight and WPF.
The main ideas behind this UI architectural pattern are:

- The view part is the only one that depends on the GUI framework. This means that for iOS, the view controller is part of the view.
- The view can only talk to the view model. **Never** to the model.
- The view model holds the state of the view. This state is offered to the view via view model properties. These properties contain not only the value of the labels, but also other view related information like if the save button is enabled or the color for a rating view. But the information of the state must be UI framework independent. So in the case of iOS, the property for the color should be an enum, for example, instead of a UIColor.
- The view model also provides methods that will take care of the UI actions. This actions will talk to the model, but they never change the state of the view that is data related directly. Instead, it talks to the model and asks for the required changes.
- The model should be *autonomous*, i.e. you should be able to use the same code for the model for a command line application and a UI interface. It will take care of all the business logic.
- The model doesn't know about the view model. So changes to the view model are propagated through an observation mechanism. For iOS and a model with plain NSObject subclasses or even Core Data, KVO can be used for that (also for Swift).
- Once the view model knows about changes in the model, it should update the state that it holds (if you use value types, then it should create an updated one and replace it).
- The view model doesn't know about the view. In its original conception it uses data binding, that not available for iOS. So changes in the view model are propagated through an observation mechanism. You can also use KVO here, or as you mention in the question, a simple delegation pattern, even better if combined with Swift property observers, will do. Some people prefer reactive frameworks, like RxSwift, ReactiveCocoa, or even Swift Bond.

The benefits are as you mentioned:

- Better separation of concerns.
- UI independence: easier migration to other UIs.
- Better testability because of the separation of concerns and the decoupled nature of the code.

So coming back to your question, the implementation of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol belongs to the view part of the architecture, because of its dependencies on the UI framework. Notice that in order to use that protocol in your code, that file must import UIKit. Also methods like `tableView(:cellForRowAt:)` that returns a view is heavily dependent on UIKit.

Then, your array of `Contacts`, that is indeed your model, cannot be operated or queried through the view (data source or otherwise). Instead you pass a view model to your table view controller, that, in the simplest case, has two properties (I recommend that they are stored, not computed properties). One of them is the number of sections and the other one is the number of rows per section:

```html
var numberOfSections: Int = 0
var rowsPerSection: [Int] = []
```

The view model is initialized with a reference to the model and as the last step in the initialization it sets the value of those two properties.

The data source in the view controller uses the data of the view model:

```html
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return viewModel.numberOfSections
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return viewModel.rowsPerSection[section]
}
```

Finally you can have a different view model struct for each of the cells:

```html
struct ContactCellViewModel {
    let name: String

    init(contact: Contact) {
        name = contact.name ?? ""
    }
}
```

And the `UITableViewCell` subclass will know how to use that struct:

```html
class ContactTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var viewModel: ContactCellViewModel!

    func configure() {
        textLabel!.text = viewModel.name
    }
}
```

In order to have the corresponding view model for each of the cells, the table view view model will provide a method that generates them, and that can be used to populate the array of view models:

```html
func viewModelForCell(at index: Int) -> ContactCellViewModel {
    return ContactCellViewModel(contact: contacts[index])
}
```

As you can see the view models here are the only ones talking to the model (your `Contacts` array), and the views only talk to the view models.

Comment: @jorge Should the cell's subviews be bound to the cell view model with some sort of observational mechanism as well? Or do you just set the view model in cell for row and call `configure()` right after?

Comment: @jorge According to you, there will be one viewModel for TableviewController and another viewModel for TableviewCell right ? Is it a good approach ?

Comment: @AP_ i think that's exactly what he means

Comment: @jorge  how to add actions for buttons in uitableview cell in mvvm?

Comment: VMs are supposed to keep the states of the views so it's not a good idea to generate a new VM every time. Instead, create a list of VMs for cells in VC's VM and pass the VMs to VC for different index paths.

Answer (score -6):

Unless you have a specific problem that's solved with `Model-View-ViewModel` then attempting to adopt it just for 'best practices' is going to end up introducing a lot of unnecessary complexity.

Your data-source is what's responsible for populating your table. Nothing other than your datasource needs a reference to `contacts` as it will update your table with this data.

`View Models` only come into play when you need to do complex UI interactions and updates. The VM is responsible for encapsulating the state of your view, things like...

1. Values of textfields
2. Which checkboxes/radio buttons are selected
3. Colors of elements
4. Animation logic
5. Dependencies between UI elements

When changes are made to your View, your `View Model` is responsible for making updates to your `Model` (when necessary) in order to reflect the changes that have been made to that `Model` through the UI.

**With all that said, View Models don't make sense in IOS** that's because IOS makes use of `View Controllers` in the design methodology called `MVC` (Model-View-Controller)

Comment: First, I'm using MVVM not because it's fancy but because it makes possible to write tests easier, it separates presentation logic and business logic which MVC doesn't (because of viewcontroller design). Second, MVVM is fine on iOS, it's just an upgrated version of MVC. Third, because ViewController and View are so tightly coupled, this equality is almost 100% true: ViewController = View, Apple's version of MVC looks more like this: View/ViewController -> Model. So View/ViewController can talk to Model, and Model only notifies View/ViewController when updates must be performed.

Comment: Stating that MVVM is an "upgraded version of MVC" doesn't make it true, because it isn't. They are completely different approaches to the same problem (Views and their state). In iOS views don't need a VM because they already hold their own state which is updated by the ViewController.