# Best Approach to make Calculation in tableviewcells and sums up in UILabel

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, viewmodel

**My Cart looks like this**

[image]

What should be the best approach to do calculation of all cells and sums up total Amount label

Cart Working like this :

Increment in cell's item doubles the value of price label but when i dequeue new cell it already has that increment value

When tried to work with custom delegate , Delegate always shows nil

What should I do ? why my delegate is always nil ?

**TableViewCell**

```
class ShoppingCartCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var cellView:UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productImageView:UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productName:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var brandName:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productPrice:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var modifier1Lbl:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var modifier2Lbl:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var counterBtns:[UIButton]!
    @IBOutlet weak var counterLbl:UILabel!


    var delegate : cellDelegateFunc?
    override func layoutMarginsDidChange() {
        super.layoutMarginsDidChange()
        contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10))

        productImageView.layer.cornerRadius = productImageView.frame.height / 4
        cellView.roundUIViewWithShadow(cornerRadius: 4, shadowColor: .darkGray)
        cellView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cellView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        cellView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        cellView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero

    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        cellView.layer.cornerRadius = cellView.frame.height / 16
        productImageView.layer.cornerRadius = productImageView.frame.height / 16
    }


    @IBAction func counter(_ sender:UIButton){

        self.delegate?.countItems(self)
    }

}
```

**CartViewController (Particular Portion)**

```
class ShoppingBagVC: UIViewController , cellDelegateFunc {
    func countItems(_ cell: ShoppingCartCell) {
        print("print")
    }
}
```

**Protocol**

```
protocol cellDelegateFunc : class {
    func countItems(_ cell:ShoppingCartCell)
}
```

**CellForRow**

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if cartAllData[indexPath.row].deal.data != nil {
       let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell3", for: indexPath) as! ShoppingCartDealCell
        cell.originalPrice = Int(cartAllData[indexPath.row].deal.data!.dealPrice)
        cell.productName.text = cartAllData[indexPath.row].deal.data?.dealName
        cell.productPrice.text = "Rs.\(String(cell.originalPrice))"
        cell.freeItem.text = cartAllData[indexPath.row].deal.data?.freeProduct
        cell.productImageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: cartAllData[indexPath.row].deal.data!.imageURL), completed: nil)
        return cell
    } else {
         let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! ShoppingCartCell
        var originalPrice = Int()

                  var price : Int = 2{
                      didSet {
                          cell.productPrice.text = "Rs.\(String(price))"
                      }
                  }

                  var count : Int = 1{
                      didSet {
                          cell.counterLbl.text = String(count)
                          price = originalPrice * count
                      }
                  }



                  if let value = cartAllData[indexPath.row].deal.data?.quantity {
                      cell.counterLbl.text = String(value)
                  }
        if let value = cartAllData[indexPath.row].product.data?.quantity {
            cell.counterLbl.text = String(value)
        }
        originalPrice = Int(cartAllData[indexPath.row].product.data!.productBasePrice)
        cell.productPrice.text = "Rs.\(String(originalPrice))"
        cell.productName.text = cartAllData[indexPath.row].product.data?.productName
        cell.productImageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: cartAllData[indexPath.row].product.data!.imageURL), completed: nil)
        cell.modifier1Lbl.text = cartAllData[indexPath.row].product.data?.modifier1
        cell.modifier2Lbl.text = cartAllData[indexPath.row].product.data?.modifier2
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you set the cellDelegateFunc to the CartViewController?

Comment: You have included UI related code but doing calculations is not a UI task, it is something you should do with your data source in the view controller or a specific model class.

Comment: Post the code to your `cellForRowAt` method

Comment: Check the updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @joakim said in comment you are doing calculations in a UI! and it's not a correct way

When a UITableView scrolls every cell will reload because of reusing and every cell will lose its state because it loads again. so you must store state of each cell in a Model and pass it to your cell each time a cell loads.

As you requested **The Best approach** would be to use a ViewModel or a Presenter  to store state of a View (here your cell) and in every load you feed that View (for example in your **cellForRow**) with the stored States or Properties

Comment: I know about that doing calculation is wrong in Cell class but problem is that i dont have idea to do it in model class for every individual cell

Comment: @HanzalaRaza You must search for examples of using Design Patterns (ViewModel Or Presenter, ...) with TableViewCell see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38957731/3472667